# Как определить видимость элемента с Puppeteer?

Tags: тестирование, test-automation, puppeteer

Согласно [документации](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-elementhandleboundingbox), elementHandle.boundingBox() возвращает null, когда элемент невидим. Однако когда я выполняю тесты, подобный ответ меня не устраивает. Тест опрашивает множество элементов и мне нужны детали когда он "падает". Как же все-таки получить полное состояние видимости элемента?

Answer (score 0):

Для себя я решил задачу следующим образом. Я собираю состояние по критериям видимости таким как:

- доступность в DOM  (isAvailable)
- свойство CSS display не равно none
- свойство CSS visibility не равно hidden
- свойство CSS opacity не равно 0
- видимость в рамках текущего viewport

API выглядит так:

```
const elh = await page.$( "#element" ),
      result = await target( elh ).isVisible();
```

Пример результатов:

```
{ 
    "isAvailable": true,
    "display": "none",
    "visibility": "visible",
    "opacity": 1,
    "isIntersecting": false
  }
```

И наконец код метода:

```
/** 
   * @param {ElementHandle} elementHandle
   * @returns {Function}
   */
  function target( elementHandle ) {
    return {
       /**
       * Check if element is visible in the DOM
       * @returns {Promise<Object>}
       **/
        isVisible: async function(){
          if ( elementHandle === false ) {
            return {
              isAvailable: false
            };
          }
          const isIntersectingViewport = await elementHandle.isIntersectingViewport(),
                handleOpacity = await page.evaluateHandle( ( el ) =>
                  window.getComputedStyle( el, null ).getPropertyValue( "opacity" ), elementHandle ),
                handleVisibility = await page.evaluateHandle( ( el ) =>
                  window.getComputedStyle( el, null ).getPropertyValue( "visibility" ), elementHandle ),
                handleDisplay = await page.evaluateHandle( ( el ) =>
                  window.getComputedStyle( el, null ).getPropertyValue( "display" ), elementHandle ),
                opacity = parseFloat( await handleOpacity.jsonValue() ),
                visibility = await handleVisibility.jsonValue(),
                display = await handleDisplay.jsonValue();

          return {
            isAvailable: true,
            display,
            visibility,
            opacity,
            isIntersecting: isIntersectingViewport
          };
        }
    };
  }
```